# Would like to create a tag for a game - is this ok? can someone help?

Tags: discussion

A community of Realm of Empires players (www.realmofempires.com) would like to use this stackexchange for their Q&A site and we where thinking of creating a tag that would group all those questions.

First of all, is that an appropriate use of this site? I see a lot of game specific tags but I wanted to make sure

Second, it appears a new user cannot create a tag. Could someone create it for us? If so, tag of "ROE" (preferred) or "Realm-Of-Empires" would be great.

Comment: just noticed the new tag, THANKS GUYS!!

Comment: Just be sure to *use it* within 24 hours, or the system will auto-delete it.

Comment: @LessPop_morefizz shouldn't this question be on the meta?

Comment: @Ender um... Er... It is?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I knew that! Of course I knew that!!  I was just checking to see if YOU knew that! Yea...

Comment: Incidentally, for future reference, we tend to prefer tags with the full game name in them (thus "realm-of-empires" vs. "roe") when possible for reasons of clarity. We *do* have a 25 character limit, but in order to lessen confusion for games that can potentially share acronyms and for those who don't play those games, it's generally preferred to write the full name out for the tag. :) We *can* set up tag synonyms if necessary. Welcome to the site and we look forward to you and your community's contributions!

Answer (score 11):

Using this site as your Q&A is perfectly fine, but do keep in mind that questions must still adhere to the rules of this site. **If you plan on officially sending your players here, we would appreciate if you ask them to take a glance at our [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) and act accordingly.**

Our FAQ is really not that long (well, if you don't expand the items there) and gives a pretty good idea of what this site is, and isn't, for.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, questions about facebook games are considered on topic here.

Our tagging standard is that we create a tag for any game that has questions about it, so yes, a game-specific tag is appropriate.

In the future, if you'd like to ask a question about a game for which a tag doesn't yet exist, just go ahead and ask it, and use an appropriate other tag (such as [ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) or [facebook](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) if we even have that one), and flag it for mod attention or leave a comment on your own question to have someone come in and fix it. As a community, we're pretty good about taking care of that sort of thing pretty quickly.